# How to pass an enum to a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums

I have a xml where I read from the types of the object that needs to be created,the problem lies to how I can pass the enum without having to use a switch/if statement.

```
   enum ObjectType {A,B,C};

   void parseXML(const string& fileName)
   {
     //Open-read file etc...

     ObjectType objType = xmlObject.type(); <- the structure provided from the xml parser that I use(codesynthesis)

     ObjectParameters params = gatherParameters(xmlObject);

     auto createdObj = factory.createObject<objType>(params);
                                           ^^^^^
  }
```

A constant expression is required,so do I have to map the provided types or is there any faster way? 
And if so is there a way to use the enum as a tag/synonym for the classes?

Comment: Did you try you cast it?

Comment: If the template type for `createObject` expects the type of the object to create then you are going to need a switch to map the `enum` to a type.

Comment: @ShikatsuKagaminara yes it asks for a constant expression as well since I use the givenObjectType in the  brackets < >

Comment: Normal way is to pass the enum as parameter and let the function return an object based on a switch or a map with registered objects.  Now you want runtime polymorphism handled by compiletime polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
auto magic_switch=[]( auto value, auto limit ){ // limit must be compile time type value
  return [value,limit](auto&&f){
    auto* pf=std::addressof(f);
    using ptr=decltype(pf);
    auto index=indexer<limit>();
    using R=decltype((decltype(f)(*pf))(limit));
    using Sig=R(*)(ptr pf);
    static const auto table=index(
      [](auto...Is)
      ->std::array<Sig, decltype(limit){}>
      {
        return {{
          +[](ptr pf)->R
          {
            return (decltype(f)(*pf))( decltype(Is){} );
          }...
        }};
      }
    );
    return table[value](pf);
  };
};
```

Where indexer is

```
template<std::size_t I>using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>constexpr index_t<I> index_k{};
template<class=void, std::size_t...Is>
auto indexer(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&&f){
    return f( index_k<Is>... );
  };
}

template<std::size_t N>
auto indexer(){
  return indexer(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Then your code;

```
auto createdObj = factory.createObject<objType>(params);
// work with it
```

Becomes:

```
magic_switch( objType, index_k<3> )
([&](auto index){
  auto createdObj = factory.createObject<(ObjectType)index>(params);
  // work with it
});
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23d88095e4337184).

Note you end up in subscope within a lambda; there is no way to avoid that.

Comment: woah,thank you man that was quick!!
haha, i am trying a solution  with one of your older answers to a similar question for the mapping

Comment: Is there any workaround for this to work on c++11? 
I am limited to using gcc 4.8.4  and c++11

Comment: @t.zak I have written many magic switches on stack overflow.  You will have to move the lambda body out into a separate class, and write the switch differently, but possible.  Google should find many examples( yakk, on this site, "magic switch").  Price of adding version tag after posting!